# Can we post carousel/collection from Wordpress Blog/Event Page to Linkedin?

Tags: wordpress, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

Please help me with this

I want to post images from a wordpress blog when i share it to linkedin through a button on that blog post page itself, when i click that, the images in that blog/event page will be sshare on linkedin as carousel or collection.

is it doable?

I checked lots of wp plugins or online ways to do, but failed to find